# Xamarin can't find binding property

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to understand the issue of this, bit it doens't work at all...

So what I'm trying to do is to make an menu with a listview as it's content. Now, I have the view, with binding properties, and I have a class in which I make the list. Here is the code:

```
public class MenuList
    {
        public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }

        // Initialize the Pokemon object thing :p
        //public MenuList() { }

        // Here we make the pokemon list :D
        public static List<MenuList> GetMenuItems()
        {
            return new List<MenuList>()
            {
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Radio" },
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Shout/request lijn" },
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Rooster" },
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Geschiedenis" },
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Medewerkers" },
                new MenuList() { Icon="RadioApp.Assets.Icons_menu.account.png", Title="Over deze app" },
            };
        }
    }

<ListView  x:Name="menuItemsLVW" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="Black" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Now, I get the errors : `[0:] Binding: 'Icon' property not found on 'RadioApp.Model.MenuList', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Image.Source'`

I have no idea why it returns the error, because as far as I can see, tis should work?

The class I generate the page:

```
public partial class Menu : ContentPage
    {
        private List<MenuList> lstOfAllMenuItems;

        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstOfAllMenuItems = MenuList.GetMenuItems();

            menuItemsLVW.ItemsSource = lstOfAllMenuItems;

            //Debug.WriteLine(lstOfAllMenuItems[0].Title);
            //Debug.WriteLine(lstOfAllMenuItems[0].Icon);
        }
    }
```

If I do the debug, it just returns the correct item...

Comment: Try {Binding path=Icon} and {Binding path=Title}.

Comment: That returns `No property, bindable property, or event found for 'path', or mismatching type between value and property`

Comment: the Icon property should just be a string

Comment: @Jason that doesn't matter here..... Since the way you give the property type doesn't help at all here....

Comment: Does the binding for Title work?

Comment: non of the bindings work here...

Comment: there must be something else going on then - this is a pretty simple case of data binding.  Not sure what to tell you to try.

Comment: @Srusti Thakkar What's are you talking about? There is no difference between string and String in c#. It's C#, not java.

Comment: Could you please create a small app which reproduce this problem for us? So we can start testing that?

Comment: The strange thing I discovered yesterday night, was that if I do a foreach loop in the list and plot the values in de debug window, it works, from the moment I remove that, it doesn't work anymore... really strange...